# rubycocoa 0.13.2, snow leopard & ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, ruby-cocoa

I have a rubyCocoa project, that was written for ruby 1.8.6, RubyCocoa version 0.13.2. The class tree is built from a xcdatamodel. I'm trying to migrate it to Snow Leopard. When trying to run, the program enters the endless loop, because it fails on method/property lookup. Seems, it has a problem to initialize a data model. It worked fine with 1.8.6. Is there some known caveats for creating a class tree from a database in snow leopard, xcode 3.2?

Any clues will be greatly appreciated

Nava

Comment: Can you post your code? it will help to explain what is the problem.

Comment: It's a whole project. I integrated rubycocoa 0.13.2 while in Leopard and it worked fine. now it's a part of the system, seems everything should work the same, but xcdatamodel fails to initialize some property and the program enters endless loop. Each time it's the same property, innocence string no more than that. May be RubyCocoa in 10.6 was built with GCC 4.2? And my project still with 4.0?
Any clues? I'm new to ruby and to rubycocoa please help me to pinpoint the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RubyCocoa 1.0.0 (rev. 2277), not the release solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! Whoever experiences the same problem, please visit the link:

[Fix to cocoa CoreData wrapper classes](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/rubycocoa/lists/archive/devel/2007-April/000845.html)